# how do I run a mir application from a command line?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, mir

I want to run webapp-container from the local terminal on an Ubuntu Touch phone, or run it from an ssh session into the phone. I am looking for something like the DISPLAY environment variable to set to tell it where to put the user interface, but this is MIR, not X, so I can't do that. Is there a way to start Mir clients and tell them what their server is?

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ webapp-container http://www.ubuntu.com
UbuntuClientIntegration: connection to Mir server failed. Check that a Mir server is
running, and the correct socket is being used and is accessible. The shell may have
rejected the incoming connection, so check its log file
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Do I have to do something to make the Mir socket accessible?

Answer (score 2):

Mir appears to use the `MIR_SOCKET` environment variable, which I found on an Ubuntu phone (emulated) to be in `/var/run/mir_socket`.

```
export MIR_SOCKET=/var/run/mir_socket
```

and you might be set.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way is just to pass it the desktop file of an unconfined application (that application can't be running though), e.g.

```
webapp-container http://www.ubuntu.com --desktop_file_hint=/usr/share/applications/webbrowser-app.desktop
```

Comment: why does that work? would it work for other Mir apps?

Comment: It's not finding Mir that's the problem, it's the security layer which prevents the Mir connection; the desktop_file_hint tells it that the application should be run using the profile of the .desktop file you pass to it (when you launch an app via the launcher this all gets done automatically). It should work with pretty much any apps.

Comment: that does work, but only for stuff in /usr/share/applications it seems, this doesn't work:
webapp-container http://www.facebook.com --desktop_file_hint=/custom/click/com.ubuntu.developer.webapps.webapp-facebook/current/webapp-facebook.desktop

Comment: The important thing is that you use the desktop file of an unconfined application (webapp-facebook isn't unconfined). So in this case you'd want to run: webapp-container facebook.com --desktop_file_hint=/usr/share/applications/webbrowser-app.desktop