# Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition: is it possible to call from terminal?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition: is it possible to make a call from terminal?

Comment: This seems interesting but info is hard to find so start small can you run ` dialer-app` and does the dialer open ? https://launchpad.net/dialer-app

Answer (score 2):

Just launches the application with the number:

```
dialer-app tel:///666 --desktop_file_hint=/usr/share/applications/dialer-app.desktop
```

(how to run apps on Mir from command line: [how do I run a mir application from a command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611274/how-do-i-run-a-mir-application-from-a-command-line))

In the source code:

```
        ...
        // do not call the number directly, instead only populate the dialpad view
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(mainView, "populateDialpad", Q_ARG(QVariant, value), Q_ARG(QVariant, QString()));
        ...
```

Comment: This makes sense in a few ways as you wouldn't want apps phoning people automatically :) .There may not be a permission for apps to access the messaging functions like there is on Android

Comment: I think that the developer just wasn't in the mood to parse an additional option.